# How to plot 2D images after 3D mesh in OpenGL and pygame?

Tags: python, opengl, 3d, pygame

In pygame I have created main menu with 3 buttons, the first two buttons plot 2D graphs, if I press "backspace" or "escape" it returns to the main menu with the three buttons. The last (third) button, plots 3D mesh from STL file.
[1]

**The problem:** I can very easily navigate between 1st and 2nd button, but if I at least once plot the 3D mesh, then I can press anymore 1st and 2nd button.

**Code to plot the 3D mesh:** (Unfortunately I'm not allowed to upload the whole code due to private data.)

**My thoughts about the problem:** I would assume I have a problem due to enabled depth testing and blending when I render polygons in my application.
I have tried to disable depth testing and blending.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like button A and button B trigger calls to render a plot in the plane of the screen (this is a 2D render which requires an orphographic projection). Based on your code, button C triggers a call to render the 3D model with a perspective view matrix.

When you switch between rendering calls, you need to ensure that you reset the view matrix appropriately (set an orphographic projection matrix before button A/B render code is called). It looks like you might be forgetting to set the view matrix to an orphographic projection before the render code triggered by button A/B. Therefore, when you press button A and button B after the result of button C, it is trying to render using the previously set perspective projection matrix giving strange results.

You must create an orthographic projection matrix and load it before rendering in 2D. You can set this with a call to `gluOrtho2D` after setting matrix mode in the 2D code snippet, similar to your call to `gluPerspective` in the 3D code snippet. [This page describes in great detail](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html#example1) how to create the orthographic matrix required (navigate to the Projection Matrix (GL_PROJECTION) section for a detailed explanation and sample code).

Comment: Make sure you set the parameters to gluOrtho2D correctly.  Checking the api, the signature is: gluOrtho2D(GLdouble left ,GLdouble right ,GLdouble bottom,GLdouble top). You must set these based on the coordinate system you use. E.g. (-1, 1, -1, 1) for a coordinate system with (0, 0) at screen centre, value of (1, 1) top right corner and (-1, -1) at bottom left corner. This ofcourse must be consistent with the coordinates used to render the plot. I.e. whether using screen coordinates or -1 to 1 as in this example.